# Eloquent: Has Many Through Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out a relationship but I can't seem to solve the issue.

So what my script does first is checking if there is a valid session where status = 0.

Then I want to check if there is a valid trial where status = 0 ->first() associated with that session.  And if so, I want to grab all the relevant data related by trial_id.

I understand what logic is required. However, I am wondering if there is a method to do this with as little commands as possible using Eloquent relationships.

Specifically, once i have the $session object. How can I filter the trials, in order to get the appropriate stimuli_tracker data?

The important components to the relationships for the table is as follows:

**Sessions**

- **id** (has one to many relationship to trials(sessions_id)
- user_id (foreign key)
- status

**Trials**

- id (one to many relationship with stimuli_tracker)
- sessions_id (foreign key)
- status

**Stimuli_Tracker**

- trials_id (foreign key)
- stimulus
- stimulus_type

Sessions Model

```
class Sessions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sessions';



    public function stimuliTracker()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\StimuliTracker', 'App\Trials', 'sessions_id','trials_id');
    }
}
```

Trials Model:

```
class Trials extends Model
{
    public function stimuli()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(App\StimuliTracker);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have tried in artisan tinker to

```
$object = \App\Session::where(arg);
```

then I tried to

```
$object->stimulus
```

but didn't work. I tried a few other fields but I only received null. Maybe I'm not getting how to grab the content properly

Comment: You can achieve this by using joins. I think that there is no way to do it without eloquent relations :(

Comment: What you have on your sessions model should work. Did you get an error or something?

Comment: refer to edit. I am receiving a null on any request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$object->stimulus is an undefined attribute based on what you've shown in your code.

To access the stimulus information for your session, you have to use the name of the relationship, which in this case is:

```
$object->stimuliTracker
```

The thing is that this will return an Eloquent Collection because it is a hasManyThrough relationship (which is a hasMany of a hasMany).

I'm assuming that the 'stimulus' attribute belongs to the StimuliTracker class. If this is the case, then you will need to loop through your StimuliTracker Collection to extract it:

```
foreach ( $object->stimuliTracker as $record )
{
    $stimulus = $record->stimulus;
    // do something with $stimulus
}
```

EDIT (Added):

If you are just looking for an array of the values in the 'stimulus' attribute, you can get that with the lists() method:

```
$stimulus_values = $object->stimuliTracker->lists('stimulus');
```

Comment: Yes 'stimulus' belongs to StimuliTracker. However, when I return $object-stimuliTracker, I get all the data (multiple rows). When I do foreach method. All I get is a single row when i return $stimulus. How would I get all the data from the $object->stimuliTracker

Comment: Your second sentence in that comment says you get "all the data", so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: If you're asking for an array of the stimulus attribute, then you'll want to use: $object->stimuliTracker->lists('stimulus');

Comment: Actually. That does work very nicely. Now my last question. What if I need two columns in that table. stimulus and stimulus_type?

Comment: Seems to work with ->toArray() instead of list. Thanks